# MYSQL extractValue

Tags: mysql, sql, xpath

I have following xml

```
  <ns8:vehicles>
                <ns8:vehicle vinNumber="asdaqwe" model="lambda" make="xdeee">
                    <ns8:registration number="e123asdz23" date="2016-07-22"/>
                    <ns8:usage type="Passenger"/>
                </ns8:vehicle>
            </ns8:vehicles>
```

and trying to get elements vinNumber and registration number using extractValue in query
so I'm doing something like this:

```
select ExtractValue(databasexmlfield, '//ns8:vehicle//ns8:registration')
select ExtractValue(databasexmlfield, '//ns8:vehicle//ns8:registration number')
select ExtractValue(databasexmlfield, '//ns8:vehicle//ns8:registration::number')
```

none of these works returns xpath error or returns 0 data.
How do I get this working?

it's working when the xml is presented like that:

```
<holder id="1">
    <title>Mr</title>
```

so when I type select ExtractValue(databasexmlfield,'//holder //title')
it prints Mr.
Mysql version is latest 5.5

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```sql
SELECT
  ExtractValue(@`xml`, '//ns8:vehicle/attribute::vinNumber'),
  ExtractValue(@`xml`, '//ns8:vehicle/ns8:registration/attribute::number');
```

See [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cAuH1jgBA7Tgzi4qZCYcGp/0).